# How can I call my function in my utils.py of my Django app?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to call `python manage.py load_json data.json` but I get
`Unknown command: 'load_json'`. Am I missing something? The utils.py is not in my core app. I also tried `python manage.py inventory.load_json data.json` and that didn't work either, inventory is the app that I have my utils.py file in.

Comment: `load_json` is not a Django management command - see the full list here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/. Did you mean to use `loaddata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `utils.py` file that contains a function called `load_json` that you want to be able to execute from the command line within the context of your application. Unfortunately `manage.py` doesn't know anything about your utility function, so when you try to run it like this it fails.

If you want to run a script, function, utility etc. from the command line using `python manage.py my_function`, then you need to register that function as a management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Note that there is a built-in management command called `loaddata` that can load data from fixtures. It can load from JSON if you're using 2.*. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata

Answer (score 0):

create folder structure like

```
-utils
  -management
     __init__.py
     commands
         __init__.py
         load_json.py
```

write your logic in load_json.py, there after run the same command

```
python manage.py load_json
```

it will run the currespongin handle function [More Information here..](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)